# What is the best OPEN-Source ETH explorer? (alternative to etherscan)

Tags: ether, etherscan, myetherwallet, explorers, explorer-api

What is the best OPEN-Source ETH explorer?

I ve seen the following answer : [Open Source Ethereum Blockchain Explorer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/open-source-ethereum-blockchain-explorer)

Is these the only 3 open source alternatives to etherscan?

EthVM
BlockScout
OpenSTExplorer

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run it locally [Otterscan](https://github.com/wmitsuda/otterscan) is really nice.

If you are thinking about running a block explorer for your own network the ones you listed might be a better choice (especially [BlockScout](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout), as it is quite widely used)